# How can I convert reflection method result to array?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, entity, iqueryable

I'm using reflection with parameter. I'm getting results as `IQueryable`. I want to convert this `ToArray()`. I tried Array instead of `IQueryable` but not working like following code:

```
var countries = entity.Countries.ToArray();
```

How can i get same result with this code?

```
public IQueryable Get(string tableName)
{
    var result = _db.GetType().GetProperty(tableName)?.GetValue(_db, null) as IQueryable;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How about this? ``public TypeOfQueryResult Get(string tableName)
{
    […]
    return result.ToArray();
}``

Comment: What type is _db? What are you expecting in the array? GetValue returns the value of a specified property?

Comment: It would be useful if you could mention the return type of the property you are invoking (what type of data would be in the array) ?

Comment: @dumetrulo result.ToArray() (does not contain a definition for ToArray

Comment: @Wheels73 _db is Entity

Comment: @AnuViswan in array have  CountryID:Value and CountryName:Value

Comment: This IQueryable result working with kendo Grid with dynamic model. This array will create viewData for dropdowns in the grid.